# Skyrim crashes when fast traveling to location which was fast traveled by riding dragon

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues, skyrim-dragonborn

I have two Skyrim DLCs installed, Dawnguard and Dragonborn, I'm playing on Windows 10 PC. I used a Bend Will shout to tame a dragon and fast traveled to Whiterun Stables while riding it. Everything was OK, but ever since then fast traveling to Whiterun Stables (without dragon) causes a game to crash to the desktop. I think that this would happen with any location. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Can you check if it indeed only happens when traveling to the Whiterun Stables? I think I remember there being a bug with that location specifically.